# localhost:3000 This site can’t be reached after installing http-proxy-middleware

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am building a newsletter sign-up form that uses .netlify-lambda to send my form submission to Mailchimp. I installed http-proxy-middleware to help the front end find the netlify-lambda folder. After writing the proxy setup code below my React start script stopped working. It appears the proxy setup below is interfering with localhost:3000.

My proxy setup looks like this

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    console.log('Using proxy...')
    app.use(proxy('/.netlify/functions/', { 
        target: 'http://localhost:9000/',
            "pathRewrite": {
                "^\\.netlify/functions": ""
            }
    }));
};
```

If the target is localhost:9000 why is it interfering with localhost:3000?
When I start my Lambda server it says: `Lambda server is listening on 9000`.

I am also getting this error when trying to compile my client app.
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Short answer (for @lachnroll and anyone who might be encountering the same problem):

Please use `const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware")` and `app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/.netlify/functions/' ...)...)` , instead of using `const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');` and  `app.use(proxy("/.netlify/functions/" ...)...)` , it should work.

Long one:

I've come across the same "can't be reached" thing in a React project when using http-proxy-middleware(2.0.3), until I changed *const **proxy** = require('http-proxy-middleware');* and ***proxy**("/.netlify/functions/" ...)* to *const { **createProxyMiddleware** } = require("http-proxy-middleware");* and *app.use(**createProxyMiddleware**('/.netlify/functions/' ...)...)* , I think the ***proxy*** has been removed, see: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#readme